# Why doesn't Factory Girl let me create a sequence with a block in braces?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, factory-bot

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  sequence :email do |n|
    "user#{n}@example.com"
  end

  factory :user do
    email {FactoryGirl.generate :email}
    password "abc"
    admin false
  end
end
```

works just fine but if I do

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  sequence :email {|n| "user#{n}@example.com"}

  factory :user do
    email {FactoryGirl.generate :email}
    password "abc"
    admin false
  end
end
```

I get the following error

```
/Users/brad/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:235:in `load': /Users/brad/Ruby_Rails/acute_pain/spec/factories.rb:2: syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting keyword_end (SyntaxError)
  sequence :email {|n| "user#{n}@example.com"}
                   ^
```

Whaaaaa?

I'm using Factory Girl 3.1.0 and Rails 3.0.10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be careful with the parameters! :)

```
sequence(:email) {|n| "user#{n}@example.com"}
```